# Cannot resolve dependencies and plugins for Cargo tracker application

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, java-ee-5

I downloaded the Cargo-tracker application code from git hub.
Configured glassfish 4.1.1 application server in Intellij ultimate edition.

Find pom.xml below

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>net.java</groupId>
<artifactId>cargo-tracker</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>cargo-tracker</name>
<url>https://github.com/javaee/cargotracker/</url>

<properties>
    <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <netbeans.hint.j2eeVersion>1.7</netbeans.hint.j2eeVersion>
    <netbeans.hint.deploy.server>gfv3ee6</netbeans.hint.deploy.server>
    <webapp.databaseTempDir>/tmp</webapp.databaseTempDir>
    <webapp.graphTraversalUrl>http://localhost:8080/cargo-tracker/rest/graph-traversal/shortest-path</webapp.graphTraversalUrl>
</properties>

<!-- We need to use the PrimeFaces repository -->
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>primefaces</id>
        <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencyManagement>
    <!-- Arquillian BOM used to reduce collision between testing dependecies. -->
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.10.Final</version>
            <scope>import</scope>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Java EE API -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- GlassFish specific dependencies, could go away in Java EE 8 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- The third-party dependencies this application has -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.4</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- PrimeFaces dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>5.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>
        <artifactId>ui-lightness</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.10</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Test dependendencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Resolvers are needed in the Arquillian tests -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver</groupId>
        <artifactId>shrinkwrap-resolver-impl-maven</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>cargo-tracker</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
                <compilerArguments>
                    <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                </compilerArguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                <filteringDeploymentDescriptors>true</filteringDeploymentDescriptors>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.18.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                <systemPropertyVariables>
                    <!-- This is needed to tell the unit tests which profile
                    we are running. -->
                    <profileId>${project.activeProfiles[0].id}</profileId>
                </systemPropertyVariables>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<profiles>
    <!-- GlassFish specific version of build -->
    <profile>
        <id>glassfish</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
                <artifactId>arquillian-glassfish-remote-3.1</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0.CR4</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.4.14</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <container>
                            <containerId>glassfish4x</containerId>
                            <zipUrlInstaller>
                                <url>http://download.java.net/glassfish/4.1/release/glassfish-4.1.zip</url>
                            </zipUrlInstaller>
                        </container>
                        <properties>
                            <context>cargo-tracker</context>
                        </properties>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>

    <!-- WebLogic Profile -->
    <profile>
        <id>weblogic</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <webapp.graphTraversalUrl>http://localhost:7001/cargo-tracker/rest/graph-traversal/shortest-path</webapp.graphTraversalUrl>
        </properties>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
                <artifactId>arquillian-wls-remote-12.1.2</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0.Alpha3</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.6</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                        <filteringDeploymentDescriptors>true</filteringDeploymentDescriptors>
                        <webXml>${basedir}/src/weblogic/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.18.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                        <systemPropertyVariables>
                            <!-- This is needed to tell the unit tests which profile
                            we are running. -->
                            <profileId>${project.activeProfiles[0].id}</profileId>
                            <!-- This is needed to tell Arquillian which profile
                            we are running. -->
                            <arquillian.launch>${project.activeProfiles[0].id}</arquillian.launch>
                        </systemPropertyVariables>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Later got this one.
[![persistence][2]][2]

java: package org.eclipse.persistence.annotations does not exist

Because of this build getting file. Please help!
Please let me know for more information.

Comment: Please add your maven configuration

Comment: Please find pom.xml . Edited